# Symfony2 Sonata-project admin bundle - how to list custom data instead of orm entity

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

Sonata Admin Bundle provides CRUD, filtering, sorting, pagination etc.

I need to show some customized and processed data queried from few tables as an admin panel page. What would be the best way to integrate that kind of data with pagination, filtering and sorting? I mean... I would like to switch Doctrine Entity to custom Model class, and still get all the stuff (excluding Create/Update/Delte operations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination, filtering, and sorting all depend on model-specific implementations. You would need to create a new bundle with your own ModelManager implementing ModelManagerInterface as well as Pager, FieldDescription, and many other classes which only exist in SonataAdminBundle as interfaces and abstract classes.